# How to disable connection pooling in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, connection-pooling, firebird

I have a web application that currently uses c3p0 and Hibernate to connect to a Firebird 1.5 database.

I am facing a problem from time to time where the database just stops responding, even trying to manually restart the service doesn't have any effect, and it doesn't generate any logs, so I have to manually reboot the machine to get it working again.

I think that maybe Firebird hangs when the pool tries to acquire a specific number of connections or something like that. So, I need to test my app without connection pooling, to check if this is or is not the problem.

I can't simply remove c3p0 configs from persistence because this way Hibernate would use its own integrated connection pool. So how to do it?

Comment: I know it is not an immediate solution, but you should really consider upgrading your Firebird installation. The last Firebird 1.5 was released 6 years ago; all kinds of bugs have been fixed since then (and at minimum, if you aren't already at 1.5.6, upgrade to that).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible due to some delphi apps that use components which are tied to firebird 1.5 only.

Answer (score 3):

The most flexible solution is to use [an explicit DataSource](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/), instead of configuring the connection pooling through Hibernate. One option to configure a non-pooling `DataSource` is by using [DriverManagerDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html):

```
@Override
protected Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    //log settings
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    //data source settings
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.datasource", newDataSource());
    return properties;
}

protected ProxyDataSource newDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource actualDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    actualDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test");
    actualDataSource.setUsername("sa");
    actualDataSource.setPassword("");
    ProxyDataSource proxyDataSource = new ProxyDataSource();
    proxyDataSource.setDataSource(actualDataSource);
    proxyDataSource.setListener(new SLF4JQueryLoggingListener());
    return proxyDataSource;
}
```

This way you can choose a pooling or a non-pooling `DataSource`.

To get a better understanding of you connection pooling resources usage, you can configure [FlexyPool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) to collect metrics for:

- concurrent connections
- concurrent connection requests
- data source connection acquiring time
- connection lease time
- maximum pool size
- total connection acquiring time
- overflow pool size
- retries attempts

Comment: But this would also make use of connection pool...This is the problem (i think), i need something that makes every session open() and close() call to actually create a connection an close it, without leaving open connections idly in the pool

Comment: Then just supply your JDBC Driver DataSource that comes with no pooling or the Spring [DriverManagerDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html). There's going to be no pooling.

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't have the time to test, but sure i will test it soon and return here after!

Answer (score 1):

I found documentation for hibernate [3.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdb) and [4.3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties) that says:

> Just replace the hibernate.connection.pool_size property with
>   connection pool specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's
>   internal pool.
>
> Hibernate will use its org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
>   for connection pooling if you set hibernate.c3p0.* properties

So remove *hibernate.connection.pool_size* and any *hibernate.c3p0...* properties from configuration, than connection pooling is disabled.

Comment: Hibernate 5.6 uses built-in connection pool when those properties are not present: `HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Vlad's answer:

If somebody still faces this:

- Be sure to remove "**hibernate-c3p0**" from your classpath, if exists, since this will automatically enable MChange c3p0 connection pool.
- Another option that, you can close the connection manually when closing the entity manager:

  ```
            ....
            SessionImpl ses = (SessionImpl) session;
            close(ses.connection());
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
            ........
  ```

Good Luck